# How to make the header part of the site as low as the logo?

Tags: html, css, styling

I just changed some styling and broke my site :) and have not much clue how to set it back.

I put a new image as the logo.  Before it was large-font text.  And now the div ends at the bottom of other text and not at the bottom of the logo.

See how it is broken here: http://www.problemio.com - see on very top - i need to make the div extend to the bottom of the image on the left.

Here is my css:

```
.banner 
{
    width:60em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.3em 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.banner .site_title 
{
    background: url("http://www.problemio.com/img/ui/problemio.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    padding:5px 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffce2e;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    font-size:2.5em;
    text-align: left
}
```

and here is the HTML I use:

```
<div class="banner">
<!--  title and login/sign up go here -->
    <a href="http://www.problemio.com">
        <div class="site_title">

        </div>
    </a>
```

And I am trying to make the image appear in the site title div.  I think I should use the img tag, right? How should I augment my styles though?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting a height on your `banner` or `site_title` divs, so they are only going to be as high as the elements inside them, which in the case of the `banner` div appears to be text links.

In your CSS code, you're setting the background-url inside both the `.banner` and `.site_title` classes. This is redundant and can lead to things looking weird if you give only one of the divs a margin. Why not get rid of the `site_title` div and just make it an image? This should fix your height issues as well.

Comment: No prob. If you try this out but are still having problems, feel free to update the question with your updated code.